# How to do explicit multithreading in MATLAB using JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing

I just want to know how to do multithreading using java in MATLAB? I know there is parallel computing toolbox in MATLAB by this one can implement parallel computing and in JAVA by extending Thread Class we can do multithreading. 
 I want to execute multithreading using java code in MATLAB without using PCT of MATLAB? Please provide a code if possible.. I studied several literature but still can't be able to execute even a single program of java using MATLAB.. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Take working example form a text book, compile it, add it to the class path, run it. You have a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading through the example from [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1) on the [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) blog, which illustrates calling threaded Java from MATLAB. It's one of a four-part series discussing several other ways of implementing threads, including .NET and MEX.